# How to avoid writing three loops in this example?

Tags: c#, loops, optimization

In the below code example, how can I avoid writing 3 loops. I'm not sure how to keep the code readable and still optimize it. This is not the exact function I'm working on, but for brevity I updated it so it's for you guys to read.

```
int OrderQuantity = 5;
List<LineItem> Items = GetLineItems();
List<int> UniqueOrderIDs = new List<int>();

foreach (LineItem i in Items) {
    if (UniqueOrderIDs.Contains(i.OrderID) == false) {
        PurchaseOrder Order = GetOrder(i.OrderId);
        Order.ModifiedDate = Now;
        UpdateOrder(Order);
        UniqueOrderIDs.Add(i.OrderID);
    }
}

foreach (int id in UniqueOrderIDs) {
    decimal TaxableAmount = 0;

    foreach (LineItem i in Items) {
        If(i.OrderID == id){
            i.OrderQuantity = OrderQuantity;
            UpdateItem(i)

            TaxableAmount += i.Cost;
        }
    }

    UpdateTaxAmount(id, TaxableAmount);
}
```

Comment: I think you just need a group by LineItemId, then you'll have just one loop.

Comment: LineItemID is already unique here. OrderID is not unique.

Comment: I don't understand why this question is down voted.

Comment: So you have a problem. GetLineItems(OrderID), if you are passing OrderID, why it's returning different OrderID? It should filter just for OrderID that you're passing.

Comment: I'm sorry you are right. I get line items for multiple orders. I had a typo when I was writing the question.

Comment: Good. Now it's easier. Basically you'll have: 1-GetUniqueOrdersMethod, 2- a loop for each order (where you'll set the modified date); 3-a loop for each LineItem of that order (where you'll update the quantity and calculate the tax amount).

Comment: But wouldn't GetUniqueOrdersMethod be an extra db call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do, something like (I omit bounds checking here)

```
List<LineItem> items = GetLineItems(OrderID);
var sorted = items.OrderBy(i=>i.OrderID);

int id = sorted.First().OrderID; //get 1st element's id

foreach (LineItem i in sorted.Skip(1)) //skip 1st one
{
    if(i.OrderID == id)
    {
        i.OrderQuantity = OrderQuantity;
        UpdateItem(i)    
        TaxableAmount += i.Cost;            
    }
    else 
       id = i.OrderID;
}

....
```

You sort `LineItem` list by `OrderID`, after simply iterate over it, and while it is the same, do whatever you need to do.

There will be someone that, probably, would opt for `LINQ` solution, but to my taste, this looks much simpler and clear then `LINQ` solution might be in this situation.

Comment: so in the else part i'd be calling UpdateTaxAmount and resetting tax amount right? If yes, I thought about this solution but this was making the really hard to read. I do lot of stuff in the loop so one would have to really pay attention to see what is going inside the loop. Hence I chose the third loop...

Comment: @user3587180: right, as `else` handles the case when ID is not more equal (which suppose to happen once per ID)

Comment: @user3587180: divide that "a lot of stuff" into function calls, rearchitect it, so it's simplier to read.

Comment: Ok I agree with you answer. However, I think the if should check if the orderid <> id  and then update the tax amount. there should not be any else and the default would be to update item and increment tax amount. if you want you can update your answer... thanks for the help!

Comment: although i should mention if i add the bounded checks this method would not be pretty to read...

Answer (score 0):

I am probably missing something (getting late here) but why can't you do like this:

```
var orderIdAndTaxableAmount = new Dictionary<int, decimal>();

foreach (LineItem i in Items) {
    if (UniqueOrderIDs.Contains(i.OrderID) == false) {
        PurchaseOrder Order = GetOrder(i.OrderId);
        Order.ModifiedDate = Now;
        UpdateOrder(Order);
        UniqueOrderIDs.Add(i.OrderID);
    }

    i.OrderQuantity = OrderQuantity;
    UpdateItem(i);

    if (!orderIdAndTaxableAmount.ContainsKey(i.OrderId))
    {
        orderIdAndTaxableAmount.Add(i.OrderId, 0.0);
    }
    orderIdAndTaxableAmount[i.OrderId] += i.Cost;
}

foreach (var kvp in orderIdAndTaxableAmount)
{
    UpdateTaxAmount(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
}
```

Comment: That would work, but the method i'm working on is very big. It has lot of checks, so implementing this way would make it harder to read.. Ideally i'd implement it your way or @Tigran way..

Comment: Then I'd try to refactor some parts to own methods. For example `SetModifiedDateForPurchaseOrder(i.OrderId);` & `UpdateOrderQuantity(i);`. Of course in the given example it is a bit excessive but if your method is big I'd guess there are at least a few things that you could refactor to own methods and by that making it more readable.